# API Translate doens't work in Gtranslate goo.gl/IGx8vp

Tags: joomla

I have installed Translate API Key in GTranslate plugin in Joomla 3.4, and it doesn't work. It only keeps the previous translate articles before the end of the Free API Translate. The plugin's name: GTranslate Pro.
Any idea to resolve that?

Comment: Is your goo.gl link a link to your joomla website?

Comment: yes, is a short link to thw website with the problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade to the latest version (currently v3.0.x.37 for Joomla 3.x).
2. Try clearing the cache by logging in to the back-end and going to
   `System -> Clear Cache`.
3. You have a paid subscription so submit a support request to the
   developer.

Comment: Thanks Neil.
After talking with GTranslate support, they saiD: "Please make sure that you didn't exceed the translation API key limit" Is there a limit?